# How to concatenate a specific month inside a date variable?

Tags: php

I need to use the month of actual year, something like this

```
$mid = new DateTime('YYYY-07-01'); // this is where should work the actual year

echo $mid->modify('second monday')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `date` to get the current year.

```
$mid = new DateTime(date('Y') . '-07-01');
```